# How can I perform a search when vim displays content using "more" pager?

Tags: search

I want to see the value of a variable, so I run the command

```
:let
```

Vim displays the results of this command using the `--more--` pager.
How can I search this for a phrase, e.g. `html`?
I've looked the man page for the more pager which says `+/` is used for search but it doesn't seem to work, neither does `/` as per the less pager.

Comment: AFAIK, it's a Vim *internal* command - it looks like 'more', but the program is not called by Vim (proof: it works in Windows, too). You can still write the beginning of a variable name, than ask Vim to complete it (e.g. with `Ctrl-d`).

Comment: thanks, when I type the variable name - or in fact pretty much anything - vim wont accept it - it just prompts with `-- More -- SPACE/d/j: screen/page/line down, b/u/k: up, q: quit` in the commandline.

Comment: Write `:let ` then don't hit `Enter`, but `Tab` or `Ctrl-d` - you'll have a list of existing variables, displayed in "more" style - now hit `Esc`, write a few letters, hit `Tab` or `Ctrl-d` again ... and so on until you find the variable you want. Actually, to see the value of a variable, perhaps you should use `echo ` instead? (Or `set variable-name?` for options)

Comment: very cool, both the `Ctrl-d` and the echo trick worked nicely, thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is not the `more` pager, this is Vim's internal and minimalistic pager which doesn't have search capabilities.

But you can use the `:redir` command:

```
:redir @a    redirect output of following commands to register a
:let         list every current option and its value
G<CR>        go straight to the end of the listing and make it disappear
:redir END   stop redirection
:tabnew      open a new buffer in a new window in a new tab page
"ap          put from register a
```

… then use regular Vim commands.

Comment: oh very cool, thats a great command to know! thanks

Comment: slightly simpler: `:redir @b|sil let|redir end`

Comment: Even though it is not the `more` pager, I feel like there is room for a plugin to replace Vim's `more` pager with `less`

Comment: @MaxCoplan you could try this: https://gist.github.com/romainl/eae0a260ab9c135390c30cd370c20cd7 It's not exactly a pager but I've found it to be pretty useful.

Comment: @romainl thanks

Answer (score 28):

Vim 8 has a `execute()` command the allows you to get the output of a command. To see it to the current buffer do:

```
:put =execute('let')
```

For Vim 7 you can use [capture.vim](https://github.com/AmaiSaeta/capture.vim). It is a plugin that wraps the commands from @romainl's answer and lets you use it as

```
:Capture let
```

Comment: thats good to know, thanks. I'll check it out when I upgrade. On vim 7 Im using steve losh's clam plugin to capture large amounts of output into a new buffer. it works well too

Comment: Both this answer and @romainl's are great for different uses. This one (`:put =execute(…)`) is what I will use when I want to run a command and get the output in the same buffer. If I want the output in a different buffer, I'll use `:redir @a`; `:let`; `redir END`. This is going to help me finally get my highlighting and syntax annoyances figured out after 20 years!

Answer (score 0):

Here is working solution (that [romainl](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/54/romainl) mentioned in comment under [the answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/5730/48864)):

[Redirect the output of a Vim or external command into a scratch buffer](https://gist.github.com/romainl/eae0a260ab9c135390c30cd370c20cd7)

Description of this script is in this answer for question:

[Can listings in the awful 'more' be displayed, instead, in a vim window?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49083560/1455694)

Described and used `scratch buffer` is similar to `less` command. Navigation and search function is available in it.

---

Checked in Vim with clipboard support:

VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Dec 07 2023 15:42:49)
Included patches: 1-213, 1840, 214-579, 1969, 580-1848, 4975, 5023, 2110, 1849-1854, 1857, 1855-1857, 1331, 1858, 1858-1859, 1873, 1860-1969, 1992, 1970-1992, 2010, 1993-2068, 2106, 2069-2106, 2108, 2107-2109, 2109-2111, 2111-2112, 2112-2269, 3612, 3625, 3669, 3741, 1847
under Ubuntu 20.04

```
sudo apt install vim
sudo apt install vim-gtk3
```

[apt - How do I install vim-gnome on Ubuntu 19.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1208159/how-do-i-install-vim-gnome-on-ubuntu-19-10)