# How do you remap keys in :history or :highlight?

Tags: highlight, navigation, command-history

I use Colemak `hnei` for nav in normal mode, but my keys default to `hjkl` when when I'm viewing `:history` and `:highlight`. How do I remap these keys?

My guess is that the program may be switching to `more`. If so, how can I make vim choose `less`?

EDIT

As per D. Ben Knoble, [this quesion](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5729/how-can-i-perform-a-search-when-vim-displays-content-using-more-pager) looks pertinent.

Comment: History and highlight for me use an internal pager for vim